# When is a Divergence-Free Vector Field on the Tangent Bundle of a Riemannian Manifold Hamiltonian?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-topology, hamiltonian-mechanics

(Reposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589600/when-is-a-divergence-free-vector-field-on-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-riemannian-man) Starting with a closed, connected Riemannian manifold $(M^n, g)$, using the "product Euclidean metric" to form an associated Riemannian metric $\tilde{g}(p,v)((v_1,w_1),(v_2,w_2))) =$ $g(p)(v_1,v_2) + \langle w_1|w_2\rangle$ on $TM$ (which is naturally a symplectic manifold with natural symplectic form $\omega$), and using the definition of the divergence of a vector field on $TM$ from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137573/divergence-of-a-vector-field-on-a-manifold, when is a divergence-free vector field on $TM$ Hamiltonian? That is, when is it the case that a divergence-free vector field $X$ on $TM$ admits a smooth function $H: TM \to \mathbb{R}$ with $dH(Y) = \omega(X,Y)$ for all smooth vector fields $Y$ on $TM$?

Is this only true when $TM$ with the associated product Euclidean metric is [Kähler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold)? (Note this post [Kähler structure on cotangent bundle?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26776/k%C3%A4hler-structure-on-cotangent-bundle).)

Also, is the converse true: with the same setup, if $X$ is Hamiltonian, is it divergence-free?

Any assistance you can provide is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

See Section 2.5 of Ref. [1](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/books/Mechanics_and_Symmetry.html) (citation given below) entitled *When are equations Hamiltonian?*  The main statement for nonlinear differential equations on symplectic vector spaces is the following

> Let $X: Z \to Z$ be a smooth vector field on a symplectic vector space $(Z, \Omega)$.  Then $X = X_H$ for some Hamiltonian function $H: Z \to \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $D X(z)$ is $\Omega$-skew for all $z$.

An analogous (local) statement on manifolds can be found in Section 5.4 of [1](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/books/Mechanics_and_Symmetry.html).

**Reference**

Marsden, J. E. and Ratiu, T. S. [Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry.](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/books/Mechanics_and_Symmetry.html) *Texts in Applied Mathematics* vol. 17, Springer-Verlag, 1994 Second Edition, 1999.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look at the book (I'm not sure what $DX$ [induced map on double-tangent bundle?] and $\Omega$-skew mean in this context), but I think that's for what I'm looking. (I love Marsden as an author.)

Comment: To be sure, the additional structure of a Riemannian metric is not necessary to determine whether a given vector field is Hamiltonian or not.

Comment: Nawaf Bou-Rabee: Wonderful addition! That's very helpful.

Comment: One trip to the library later: $DX$ is the Jacobian matrix and the matrix A is $\Omega$-skew iff $\Omega(Au,v) = -\Omega(u,Av)$ for all $u,v \in Z$; thanks so much for all your help.