# $T^*M$ is a Stein manifold: A clarification on the integral complex structure involved and its relation with the canonical symplectic form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, stein-manifolds

I'm interested in understanding better the properties of the *integrable* (almost) complex structure that Eliashberg constructs on the cotangent bundle of a closed manifold $M$, whose dimension is at least $3$ (See [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~eliash/Public/269A/Stein-notes.pdf), thm 11.10).

Let $\omega_{\text{can}}$ the canonical symplectic structure on the cotangent bundle, and let $J_{\text{can}}$ a tamed a.c.s.

The statement of Theorem 11.10 says (in our setting) that given $(T^*M, \omega_{\text{can}}, J_{\text{can}}) $ we can find an exhausting Morse function $\phi$ with some properties, such that $(T^*M, \omega_{\phi}, \widetilde{J})$ is a Stein manifold. Moreover $\widetilde{J}$ is homotopic to $J_{\text{can}}$ and $\widetilde{J}$ is tamed by $\omega_{\phi}$.

The notation $\omega_{\phi}$ should suggest that the new symplectic structure is build from the map $\phi$.

> I'd like to know if we can assume that $\widetilde{J}$ is tamed by $\omega_{\text{can}}$, or what kind of relation we can force them to have.

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/26781/48216), T. Perutz concludes by saying that it seems to be the case that $\omega_{\phi}$ and $\omega_{\text{can}}$ are symplectomorphic (apparently thanks to a clever choice for $\phi$).

> I'd like to see some references for this statement, since I wasn't able to find such a symplectomorphism between the two structures anywhere in the literature.