# Kahler surface with certain topology

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, kahler-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Let $P^2 \mathrel{\tilde \times} \mathbb{R}^2$ be the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-quotient of $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$, where the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ is antipodal on $S^2$ and a reflection on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Similarly, $K^2 \mathrel{\tilde \times} \mathbb{R}^2$ is the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-quotient of $T^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$.

Can we find a Kahler surface $M$ homeomorphic to $P^2 \mathrel{\tilde \times} \mathbb{R}^2$ or $K^2 \mathrel{\tilde \times} \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Isn't $K^2 \tilde{\times} \mathbb{R}^2$ diffeomorphic to the cotangent bundle of $K^2$? According to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26776/k%C3%A4hler-structure-on-cotangent-bundle, all cotangent bundles are Kähler.